# Why lambda function getting invoked asynchronously

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-sqs

I've a lambda function which gets triggered by a SQS event. The lambda is set to consume messages in batch x number and with a batch window on y seconds, i.e. `Batch Size= x` and `Batch Window = y`. However it's noticed that lambda get triggered asynchronously with `Batch Size= x`. As far as I understand `Batch Window = y` means that lambda will poll messages for `y` seconds before it starts execution. Please advise.

Comment: So your lambda gets invoked if it reaches the required batch size reaches before the batch window? Is my understanding correct?

Comment: @Prashanna it get invoked when it reaches batch size, but the problem what I see is, it executes asynchronously with the same batch size. So for e.g. if there are 20k messages and batch size is 5k, the it will start 4 simultaneous execution with batch size of 5k

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[BathSize and BatchWindow](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-sqs.html#events-sqs-eventsource) are used to control no of times lambda is invoked, by having lambda poller accumulate messages before invoking the lambda, mostly to save cost.

BatchSize - Max no of events accumulated before lambda is invoked.
BathWindow - (Recent addition) Max amount of time events are accumulated before lambda is invoked.(max of 5 minutes)

Without BatchWindow, as soon as event(s) is available (past visibility timeout on SQS), they are sent to lambda irrespective of batchSize reaches or not. But now it waits until BatchWindow irrespective of batchSize.

However, Irrespective of BatchWindow is set or not, no of lambda instances that are run at once is never 1. SQS poller starts with max of 5 lambda threads and can scale up to 1000.

Only way to force lambda to run single threaded is by setting reserved concurrency of 1. This will result in throttling and will eventually succeed.

From the [docs](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/lambda-sqs-scaling/):

> When you configure an SQS queue as an event source and messages are
> available for processing, Lambda begins with a maximum concurrency of
> five. Optimally, Lambda functions with an Amazon SQS trigger can scale
> up 60 additional instances per minute to a maximum of 1,000 concurrent
> invocations.

With this the behavior you explained in question/comments in expected.

BathSize: 5k , BatchWindow: 5 minutes. If we trigger 20K messages at once to SQS, 5 minutes after the visibility timeout period, 4 threads will be started at once to process those 20K messages.

Comment: Many thanks! "Only way to force lambda to run single threaded is by setting reserved concurrency of 1" solved it.